# This code throws an error saying it is missing semi colon on line 11 yet I have one at the end of line 11?

Tags: syntax

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;

class Second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj1 = new Main();

        //The line below is where my ide says I need to add a ';'
        
        Main myMethod();
        System.out.println("Name: " + myObj1.fname + " " + myObj1.lname);
        System.out.println("Age " + myObj1.age);
    }
}
```

//error message: java: ';' expected
//line where shown above

This is really confusing me this syntax error where there is no error? Please help me anyone, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is the "Main myMethod()" ?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `myObj1.myMethod();`

Comment: Yes this is where the error was, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you meant `myObj1.myMethod();` on line 11.

`Main myMethod();` on line 11 is no valid Java code, thus the compiler complains.
And as the compiler does not know better, it give you its best guess on how to fix your code (which in this case is *not* by inserting another semicolon).